# Python I quit the program, but the script continues to run

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm making this game, and I want it to quit out when I close the window. Right now it works pretty well. The window closes without any struggles. However, the script itself continues to run, and I have no clue why. This is the code that ends the game, and I  don't see why it wouldn't just kill everything. Any help?

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        self.running = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Please add the entire loop since we can't see what is going on. For once your indentation seems off, the 3 last lines are indented one tab too much.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do

```
import sys
```

in your script?

Comment: I was about to have a total facepalm moment, but yes, I did do that.

Comment: This is a question about the question, but it is not an answer.